# How to get the column value inside relation outof the relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Below is my code.

[DB Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YExjP.png)

```
return $this->model
    ->select('orderNumber','orderNumber as order_id','orderDate as order_date','status')
    ->where('orderNumber','=',$id)
    ->with(array('OrderDetail'=>function($query){ 
        $query->select('productCode','orderNumber','priceEach as unit_price',DB::raw('quantityOrdered*priceEach as line_total'));
    }))
    ->with('customer')
    ->first()->makeHidden(['orderNumber']);
```

I want to get the sum of the line_total column and it should be displayed under the order section as in the below image..

[JSON Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIs3S.png)

DB Table Design

[DB Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2lFG.png)

I tried many ways, but could not achieve the expected outcome.

So your help is really appreciated.. :)

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code in the question. Also add the code you tried and what the problem is with that code.

Comment: Please post your DB tables designs

Comment: I don't think this is the right way. Eager loading should only be used to constraint or retrieve wanted target records. For further calculation please do it in controller or view or somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can add a select in main query like this:

```
->addSelect(['order_total' => DB::table('order_items')->whereRaw('order_items.order_id = orders.id')->sum('priceEach')]);
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you need something else.